# Работа с базой данных

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Как получить данные из БД, но не для обновления, как это делает

```
var query = db.Test_Cases
    .Include(c => c.StepAndExpResults)
    .ToList()
    .Select(c => new Test_Case
{
    Identifier = c.Identifier,
    Title = c.Title,
    Preconditions = c.Preconditions,
    Date = c.Date,
    Comments = c.Comments,
    Summary = c.Summary,
    StepAndExpResults = c.StepAndExpResults
}).ToList();
```

и

```
suite.all_test_cases = db.Test_Cases.ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < suite.all_test_cases.Count; i++)
{
    db.Entry(suite.all_test_cases[i]).Collection(c => c.StepAndExpResults).Load();
}
```

, а копию? Чтобы я мог менять в `suite.all_test_cases` все, что хочу, но при этом не менялись сами `db.Test_Cases`

Comment: Если не вызывать `db.SaveChanges`, то обновления не будет. Так что можно менять как угодно.

Comment: А вообще, `AsNoTracking` отключает режим отслеживания изменений.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov У меня просто есть модель Test_Suite, которая содержит список Test_Case. Так вот надо мне как-то сделать, чтобы Test_Suite сохранялось, но Test_Case не менялись (они сейчас удваиваются в бд)